# Unable to connect to TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Just recently my project has been going Offline and I'm unable to connect to TFS 2010 from my instance of Visual Studio (2012).   When I try to connect via the VS Team Explorer window I get:

```
TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server
```

In the Output window of Visual Studio it looks like it repeatedly tries to connect:

```
....
This solution is offline.  [Team Foundation Server:         http://mycollection:80/tfs/defaultcollection]
The solution was offline during its previous session and will remain offline.
This solution is offline.  [Team Foundation Server:         http://mycollection:80/tfs/defaultcollection]
The solution was offline during its previous session and will remain offline.
This solution is offline.  [Team Foundation Server:         http://mycollection:80/tfs/defaultcollection]
The solution was offline during its previous session and will remain offline.
HTTP code 404: Not Found
```

This only seems to be impacting me, and not others in my team.  I've changed my password on the off chance it had expired, and I've also restarted my machine.   A few tips have been to run a TFS tool (which I don't have as it's not a local install of TFS) or are VS2013 specific.

Does anybody have any tips I could try locally to try and connect to the server?

Comment: Can you connect to http://mycollection:80/tfs/defaultcollection using the web browser?

Comment: I can yeah, I actually managed to find the solution, so I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my particular problem, it seemed to be caused by the Cache file for TFS.

To resolve it I went to

```
C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\[Version]\Cache
```

I then cleared this directory of all files and restarted Visual Studio.